# Linting tool to disallow inline styles in HTML

Tags: html, css

Looking through some HTML templates produced for a project on which I am currently working, I've found extensive use of inline styles, eg:

`<div style="margin-top: 1em;"></div>`

I'm looking for a linting tool to plug into our Gulp pipeline to catch these usages and throw a warning.

My google-fu seems to be failing me, so does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just grep (search) through all `*.html` files for the string `style=`?

Your IDE almost certainly offers you a way to do so, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>, or some such.

If you want to see them in context, use something like [File Locator Lite](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite) for Windows or [Search Monkey](https://sourceforge.net/projects/searchmonkey/), which I have used on both Windows & Linux, to search for a line containing astring, but also show a few lines before and after.

Not necessary in this case, since you have a blanket ban, but always nice to know of the possibility.